# Unity3d moving object (cube) simple physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone have a demo for simple cube movement by Keyboard over a terrain with some mountains, which behaves physically correct.

I made a terrain with some mountains, a cube that I can control with my keyboard to move it over that terrain. This basically works fine, BUT, after my cube jumps over a small bump (mountain) and I keep accelerating... it starts to easily fly away, instead of flying a bit in the air and than falling quite fast back to the bottom. (like a car jumping over a bump).

I tried to increase Mass, still the same. It behaves kind of like a leaf in the wind.

No need for wheels and complex suspensions.

Comment: FYI for anyone googling in the future. It's likely some simple mistake, eg, did not use "actual" dimensions and masses, accidentally turned off gravity, had rigidbody settings incorrect or turned off, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with a capsule collider I suggest using a [character controller](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-CharacterController.html). There you have gravity enabled and reacting to non-trigger collidersa as well as some convenience features like configuring up to which angle your player can walk up at an inclined plane. Moving is accomplished by functions Move and SimpleMove.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a simple way , Just using transform.

For jump option you can call `transform.position.y+` (if you have 2d game) and then attach `rigidbody` component for gravity.

```
var moveSpeed : float;

function Update() 
{
  moveSpeed = Time.deltaTime * 2;

      //Transform your axis (x,y,z)

  transform.position.x+= moveSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Start () 
{

}
var speed = 5.0;
function Update (){  
    transform.Rotate(0, speed*Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Comment: the best way to do a demo like this is simply physically: ie, use "AddForce" when a key is pressed.